# Selecting text within another div- jquery

Tags: jquery, select

If you have the following divs:

```
<div class="container>
<div class="something">some text</div>

</div>


<div class="container>
<div class="something">some text</div>


</div>


<div class="container>
<div class="something">some text</div>


</div>
```

When you click on class container, how can you get the text for class something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".container").click(function(){
   var somethingText = $(this).find(".something").text(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.container').click(function(){
  var something = $('.something', this);
  alert(something.text());
});
```

use jquery Selector Context
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: which uses find() internal :D